# Setting WarningsAsErrors for entire Visual Studio solution, not just per project

Tags: visual-studio, csproj, solution

In Visual Studio you can go to a project's properties -> Build -> "Treat warnings as errors" and provide a comma-separated list of warnings to be treated as errors at build time.

This results in the following line being added to the `.csproj` file's build configuration(s): `<WarningsAsErrors>[list of warnings]</WarningsAsErrors>`

The problem with this is that when you have a large solution with dozens of projects, you'll have to set this manually or through a script for all projects, and if you make any changes you'll have to make that to all projects.

Is there any way to set this on the solution level instead of on a per-project basis?

Comment: `WarningsAsErrors` is hardly *unique* in this regard. I can't think of anything (beyond source control and which projects are even included) that *is* handled at solution level as well/instead.

Answer (score 10):

You can create a `Directory.Build.props` file in your solution containing properties you wish to set for all projects:

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WarningsAsErrors>[list of warnings]</WarningsAsErrors>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Note that after creating this file, I had to close and re-open VS2017 in order for it to read it.

Comment: Official doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2022